# Populating a DropDownList with text and values

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist in ASP.NET Webforms that I want to calculate how many years ago a certain year was.

In the first line 2002 is the current year -9 and has to be the value, and 9 is the text that is visibel and shows how many years ago 2002 was.

```
2002 9
2003 8
2004 7
2005 6
2006 5
2007 4
2008 3
2009 2
2010 1
2011 0
```

And I want 5 to be the preselected. How Do I do that? First of I dont know how to add a hidden Value (ex. 2002 to the visibel 9).

This is my start... Not far, I know...

```
 {
        int CT = DateTime.Now.Year;
        int CT10 = CT - 10;

        for (int i = CT10; i <= CT; i++)

        {
            ddlBirthYear.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need more information. Is this Winforms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.NET Webforms? ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Also, what is the underlying business problem you are trying to solve here? The problem seems odd - there is no notion of my age *in 2009*. Age would require you to know the day and month, not just the year. Unless by age you mean 'the age you turned in that year'. But either way - what is the underlying business problem you are working at solving?

Comment: do you man drop down list by dll in your title

Comment: Sorry I have updated my Question, and yes I mean Dropdownlist with ddl

Comment: @mjwills If your question is what I am going to use this for then its going to be a highscore for persons under a certain age. They are going to be abel to change for examel a highscore whith maximum 12 years old competitors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a ListItem to add a text and value

```
ddlBirthYear.Items.Add(new ListItem("text", "value"));
```

You can select that with

```
ddlBirthYear.SelectedValue = "5";
```

So your loop will look like this:

```
{
  int CT = DateTime.Now.Year;
  int CT10 = CT - 10;

  for (int i = CT10; i <= CT; i++)
  {
    ddlBirthYear.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), (CT-i).ToString()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Okey, how can I use those values then? string Year = ddlBirthYear.SelectedValue; string Age = ddlBirthYear.SelectedIndex.ToString(); Dosent work, and how do I change so Ages are displayed instead of years.

Comment: You say that string Year = ddlBirthYear.SelectedValue; does not work. What is the value of Year when you run this? It should be the value of the selected item in the dropdown. If you need to change to Ages are displayed insted of years then switch the params in the ListItem. The first param is displayed, the next is the value returned by SelectedValue

Comment: You can also try: ddlBirthYear.SelectedItem.Value if SelectedValue does not work.

Comment: Also: You dont want to repopulate your dropdown on a postback. That will cancel out your selection. You need to populate inside:  if (!IsPostBack) You can read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

Comment: Cool :) please click to say this answer was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

After you've added your items just use the `SelectedIndex` property to preselect a value 5 years ago like so:

```
ddlBirthYear.SelectedIndex = 5;
```

`SelectedIndex` property is is pointing to an *index* of an item in the list.

If you want to select a particular year by it's value you need to use `SelectedValue` property.

```
ddlBirthYear.SelectedValue = "2008";
```

Comment: I've added this to the pageload: fnFillYear(); ddlBirthYear.SelectedIndex = 2008; but the value dosent get preselected.

Comment: SelectedIndex is is pointing to an *index* of an item in the list. If you want to select a particular year by it's value you need to use `SelectedValue` property. `ddlBirthYear.SelectedValue = "2008";`

Comment: Great that worked well, you dont happen to know the rest of the question, like how I add an Index so I can use the SelectedIndex of years ago instead.

Comment: @user1007103 You don't need to *add* an index. Each element in list of items already has an index (in order that they are added starting with 0). So if you are populating the list the way you are, element at index 5 will always be 5 years ago, so if you need to pre-select a year from 5 years ago you set SelectedIndex to 5, from 8 years ago  you set it to 8, etc.