# Add both Text and Value into DropDownList (aspx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, webforms

I'm adding items into DropdowList by

```
while (reader.Read()) {

dpl.Items.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());

};conn.Close();
```

And that worked. However, I also need to add ID to work with that when an user chose an item (so I don't have work with the name instead).

I tried to solve this by following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103932/populating-a-dropdownlist-with-text-and-values);

```
dpl.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader["Name"].ToString(), reader["ID"].ToString()));
```

But I couldnt make it work.

How can I add both text and value and only displaying the text?

***EDIT:***

This is the only HTML line for my DropDownList:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="dpl" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dpl_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
```

Comment: Provide html code for dropdownlist

Comment: @Aarsh Sorry I should've provided it too, just added it.

Comment: try `dpl.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dpl.DataTextField = "Name";
                dpl.DataValueField = "Id";
                dpl.DataBind();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add in your HTML code **DataSourceId**
then provide **SqlDataSource** as same as gridview

then in data, you will get both id and name 
then make id hidden with simple CSS

OnSelectedIndexChanged get id and do whatever you to do with that id

Comment: Sorry I don't know what to do with DataSourceId etc. I dont have gridview either. It's a bit too complicate for me as this is new concept for me.

Comment: It will be very easy if you use it. You dont have to do what you did in your question if you need example please refer this link 

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-Bind-DropDownList-control-using-SqlDataSource-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try and "steal" your acceptable answer, because in my view, it's not the correct answer you're looking for. Sorry.

The `Items.Add()` method actually has **two** options for you. A `String` or a `List`. The answer lies in the `List` item.

If you use the String option, the server-side will allocate both the Value and the Text portion of the dropdownlist control to the same string value.

i.e.

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.Items.Add("I am a value and a text");
Console.Write(ddl.Items[0].Value);  //this gives "I am a value and a text"
Console.Write(ddl.Items[0].Text);   //this also gives "I am a value and a text"
```

To place a different result in `Value` as opposed to `Text`, you need to build a `list` item, and then add it.

```
ListItem li = new ListItem("I am a Text",100);
ddl.Items.Add(li);
Console.Write(ddl.Items[0].Value);  //this gives 100 
Console.Write(ddl.Items[0].Text);   //this also gives "I am a Text"
```

I hope that helped.